# IE7 and nested span in header

Tags: css, header, internet-explorer-7, html

No idea why I can't figure this out and I am sure it is simple...

I have a title that has a cut-through using the following code -

```
h2.boxtitle2 { width:100%; text-align:left; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFCC00; line-height:0.1em; margin:10px 0 10px; }

h2.boxtitle2 span { background:#fff; padding:0 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px !important; margin: 0 10px; padding: 0 5px; font-weight:normal; text-transform:uppercase; color:#666666 !important;}

<h2 class="boxtitle2"><span>Key Dates</span></h2>
```

Looks great in all browsers except IE7...  Anyone know how I can fix it there - and it is an in house website where about 40% of users are on IE7.

Comment: Might help if you post a screencap of your output...

Comment: or telling us whats wrong..

Comment: yep, need a screen cap for this one, don't have IE7 installed on any system here.

Comment: the good output is "---Title--------------------" -- in IE7 there is just "------------------------------" with very very squished (2pixels) "Title"

Comment: Have you tried setting a greater line-height on the span element?

Comment: Yes.  It sets the Title height to whatever I set the the line-height to.  It also pushes the cut-through line down.  Also when setting the line-height the text is centered vertically.  Meaning that if I set it to half the height of the text height (18px) then I get the top part of the text cut and the bottom cut at the line.  This span only wants to display over the line in IE7 (because of the border-bottom property being used as the line) instead of displaying on top of the line - which all other browsers do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Position:relative` and `z-index:2` on the span element seems to work in my IE7 but may not be the best solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/zrxqB/13/

Comment: That works the best.  I added a line-height of .5em so that the cut-through lines up basically the same as modern browsers.  Thank you.  Also just added another stylesheet for IE7 because new code didn't play well with other browsers... Love IE7.

Comment: No problem :) Yes, it's a very good idea to have it in a separate stylesheet for IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the line-height 0.1em. With this line-height there is not enough space for the heading on the row. Try other way ... png may be ...

Comment: It works but defeats the whole purpose of a cut-through line for the title.  Without the small line height for the h2 the line just underlines the entire title.

Comment: I guess what I want to do is have the SPAN just sit on top of the h2 - which it does on all modern browsers.  For IE7 The span text seems to take on the height of the h2 even if I note a height for the span.